# TFS Error: Unable to determine the workspace for this solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workspace, tfs, alm

I get this error when trying to "Go Online" with a project on a Visual Studio 2010 ALM project.

The project was previously connected to a team project on Team Foundation Server (2010), but I had to reinstall both the SQL Server and the TFS installation and I guess all that information was deleted.

Now, I'm trying to get the project into a new Team Project on TFS, and the TFS gives me this error.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What I ended of having to do was re-map the workspace within the Visual Studio 2010 IDE.

1. From the Visual Studio IDE Navigate to **FILE->Source Control->Workspaces**
2. You will see a list of workspaces.  Create a new workspace that points to your local project directory and the location of the source control folder on TFS.
3. It will ask if you want to get the latest version from Source Control, select yes or no depending on which version of your code is the most up to date.

Comment: For me for some reason it was pointing to old directory C:\Projects instead of D:\Projects. Changing the path thru your advice helped.

Answer (score 18):

Changing the path for a new workspace folder was not an option for me since the source control repository was way too large to download again.

What I did was re-binding the projects within the solution. In order to do this,

go to **FILE -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control**

Visual Studio will warn you that the binding of all projects will be removed, click ok.

After that click on the 'change source control' again and the list of all projects will appear as not connected. Choose the projects which were previously source controlled and click on 'bind' for each one.

Hopefully the bindings will be set automatically.

Comment: This is perfect solution, rather than start from scratch.

Comment: Agreed. The accepted answer proposes creating a new workspace, which is explicitly *not* what I want to do. But this answer simply fixes the bindings.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but I had to delete the 'solution'.suo file-

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebind into the source control. First disassociate current project from the TFS by clicking on File-> Source Control -> Change Source Control.

And after that From File-> Source Control -> click on Add Website/Solution to Source Control.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error File->Open-> Website -> From the left panel click on Source Control and Select specific TFS project.
After selecting specific folder, click on "Run as IIS Website" checkbox .