# Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running

Tags: android, tfs

I try to build apk file in my tfs server. When i run build, after 5 minutes tfs server tell me that my apk file was build and status ok, byt in folder not apk file , in folder only my logs.

```
 Run build_APK.bat
  F:\Android\projects\Mrdoc\TeamBuildTypes\mobile_v3R\\build_APK.bat "\\tfb\storage\mobile v3r_1.7\"
  Get last version in TFS Server...
  Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.
  Enviroment initializing...
  The system cannot find the path specified.
  Assembling...
  Deploing path:"\\tfbd\storage\mobile v3r_1.7\"
  The command "F:\Android\projects\Mrdoc\TeamBuildTypes\EOSmobile_v3R\\build_APK.bat "\\tfb\storage\mobile v3r_1.7\"" exited with code 1.
```

I ran the command **'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'**
and I saw all users but it did not help me.

```
 Overall Build Process

Get the Build

Update Build Number

Run On Agent Default Agent - test1

Get the Build Directory

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationFolderPath)

Run TfsBuild for Configuration Folder

Getting sources

Labeling sources

Generating list of changesets and updating work items

Выполнена сборка $/Doc/TeamBuildTypes/mobile_v3R/TFSBuild.proj для целевых объектов CompileConfiguration.

MSBuild Log File
If CompilationStatus = Unknown

Set CompilationStatus to Succeeded

If TestStatus = Unknown

Set TestStatus to Succeeded
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS Error: Unable to determine the workspace for this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559294/tfs-error-unable-to-determine-the-workspace-for-this-solution)

Comment: @Chisko 
not helped me,i saw this answer, update the my question

Comment: Are you using a XAML build in your case and what's your tfs version？

Answer (score 0):

First if your build service was registered with **network service**. Give a try with changing it to a windows user with enough build permission.

Moreover, please make sure you have **a workspace mapping** for your build computer and for the windows account under which build agent runs.

Take a look at this similar issue: [Team Build, fixing the "Unable to determine the workspace" error](http://angledontech.blogspot.sg/2011/09/team-build-fixing-unable-to-determine.html)