# TFS Annotation Error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

I've recently had a TFS 2015 to 2017 upgrade, and now I have this error whenever I try to do a Source Control->Annotate from the Visual Studio Solution Explorer:

> Annotation Error
>
> m_itempath or m_versionControl not set

If I try to run the annotate from the file editor, I get the different error:

> Annotation Error
>
> Unable to determine the workspace for the file C:\...

Using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.
This is a Server workspace, and all other operations seem to work as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the solutions in

- [Is there workaround for when TFPT is "unable to determine the workspace" and refreshing the cache does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455942/is-there-workaround-for-when-tfpt-is-unable-to-determine-the-workspace-and-ref)
- [TFS Error: Unable to determine the workspace for this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559294/tfs-error-unable-to-determine-the-workspace-for-this-solution)

failed to work for me.

This did work:

1. Go to Source Control Explorer
2. Right-click on the mapped folder
3. Select 'Advanced->Remove Mapping' and follow prompts. Ignore conflict screens.
4. Select 'Advanced->Map to Local Folder' and map back to the existing folder.
5. Resolve any outstanding conflicts.

After this, the annotations worked again.